# Rendering Static file in Wkhtmltopdf in Django

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf

I have followed too many answers to this but I need some more explanation on this topic as I want to know the root cause for it.

I am trying to create pdf using wkhtmltopdf.

This is my setting files look like :

`Settings.py`

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

And the URL to reference static file is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/template_pdf.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```

Or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/template_pdf.css" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///static/css/template_pdf.css" type="text/css" />
```

or

I used this too:
https://gist.github.com/renyi/f02b4322590e9288ac679545df4748d3

and provided url as :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}static/css/template_pdf.css' />
```

But the issue I understood is, all of the above except last one works perfectly while rendering view :

```
def view_pdf(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""

    context= {'title': 'Hello World!'}

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'pdf/quotation.html', context=context)
```

But for creating pdf using wkhtmltopdf it specifically needs the url to be specified like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http:localhost:8000/static/css/template_pdf.css" type="text/css" />
```

I know I am missing something in the static file. But I want to know why it works with rendering template but not with Generating pdf using wkhtmltopdf.
I dont think it is good idea to put directly domain name inside the referencing url.

A detailed solution for this would be helpful as I am very new to django.

I tried follow this answer too but nothing worked : [Django wkhtmltopdf don't reading static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445486/django-wkhtmltopdf-dont-reading-static-files)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how wkhtmltopdf works. There is nothing you can do about that, because wkhtmltopdf doesn't use your web server to render html and cannot resolve anything other than full path.

Comment: So If I switch between debug and production, I have to change the address everytime ?

Comment: if it is so than how this answer was accepted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445486/django-wkhtmltopdf-dont-reading-static-files?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I don't know why that answer was accepted. Maybe it works like that with django-wkhtmltopdf package, but I can't tell, I'm not using it.

Comment: I am using django-wkhtmltopdf only. Still I tried that thing but it doesnt work.

Comment: My advice would be that if it only works with full path then work with that. I know I do. There's no point wasting hours trying to find a different way.

Comment: And If go with production than ? I have to put my domain name instead of localhost ?

Comment: I was just trying to know because I thought there is some issue with my static configuration. So was trying to know more but rendering template works fine as usual only issue was with django-wkhtmltopdf. But I am going with your suggestion. But I will still keep this question open so people dont get confused like It happened with me by watching the answer to that question

Comment: If all you do is change debug true/false, then you can put domain name in your settings file with simple if/else statement. But usually changes between development and production environment require some sort of strategy for handling multiple environments.

Comment: it doesnt work if I keep it in settings.py . It only works if I specify full url path inside the html file

Comment: I doubt that. If you include MY_DOMAIN = 'http://my.domain.com' in your settings file and import and render that in your template the same why you did with {{ STATIC_URL }}, it will work.

Comment: Will check it more thoroughly

Answer (score 3):

I added `http://localhost:8000` explicitly in my template when running in debug mode:

In the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% if debug %}http://localhost:8000{% endif %}{% static '/css/template_pdf.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```

And I added the `debug` to the context (**EDIT**: according Sara's comment, the django template already knows the `debug` variable so it shouldn't be necessary to add it to the context.):

```
from django.conf import settings

def view_pdf(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""

    context= {
        'debug': settings.DEBUG,
        'title': 'Hello World!'
    }

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'pdf/quotation.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Django template already supports {% if debug %}, no need to pass in 'debug': settings.DEBUG in the context

Answer (score 2):

in your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

to render static files in your template django provide [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/) tag. You can use this as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/template_pdf.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```

Also make sure you have this included in your urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Don't forget to run `collectstatic` command in the end

Comment: It works while rendering view not while generating PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Comment: update your question with static settings.. so that it is easy to identify the issue

Comment: see my updated answer, you need to include these lines in urls.py

Comment: I kept this too. But no change in generating pdf. Rendering template view is correct as it was.

Comment: are you trying this locally ? or on production server.. it should work on production server.. for local serving you can change prefix to `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: I am trying this locally. where to change the prefix ?

Comment: I already specified in the question that if I put http://localhost:8000/ in the url it works.

Comment: how to define differently for production and local pls specify

Comment: use `if DEBUG` in your settings.py to differentiate.. coz value of debug must be kept false in production.

Comment: if it is so than how this answer was accepted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445486/django-wkhtmltopdf-dont-reading-static-files?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Haven't tested.. might be some catch there.. will try on my system and then come up with conclusion.

Comment: I will be glad. I will wait for your reply.

Comment: Updated my answer again, i have tested it and it's working as expected

Comment: will try and update you. Though I have tried this too previously but will try again